# How to export data from an embedded PowerBI visualization?

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, powerbi-embedded

I have embedded a PowerBI visualization onto my website.

I'd like the viewer of my website to be able to download the data that's shown in the charts.

This is easily done in the Power BI software itself- I simply click on the ellipses in the upper right hand corner and select "Export data." However, I can't see the ellipses once I've embedded the visualization/dashboard onto my website.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @user5226582 I was afraid it wouldn't be; how could I go about implementing it manually? Do you mean something like a button that runs a scrape script on whatever values are in the PowerBI iframe?

Comment: Apologies, looks like I was wrong. I did a quick search and saw feature requests for this, so assumed it was still not implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon you're using [publish to web and embed codes](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-publish-to-web/) instead of [Power BI Embedded](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/) (that's the tag you added). Export data is actually available for Power BI Embedded.

You can check out this [Power BI Embedded sample](http://azurewebsiteexperience.azurewebsites.net/dashboard/FleetSummary) which has the export data option as default:

[image: export data]

Data is downloaded in csv:

[image: data]

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete Foxan Ng answer, the export option is only available when embedding a **report** into the iframe, i've tired it with **dashboard** and **tile**, the option was not available.